# C# Change using namespace reference dll path dynamically IN .NET LIBRARY PROJECT

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

I have **a class library .net project(no config,no exe file)** and I have something like this;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using eBAControls; *<-- I want this dll to be loaded from a path in runtime.*
```

I have to make  `copyLocal` `false` for future reasons thus i need to be able to refer the dll in runtime. Other 3rd party dlls which are in same folder with this current dll **do not cause any problems** but `eBAControls` dll is not in the same folder with this current dll thus it gives the error: `Could not load file or assembly 'eBAControls`...

I can not also use reflection for that for some coding and performance reasons thus it needs to be added to references...

Shortly what i want is

```
using eBAControls = @"somepath"; <- that is set dynamically for ex while one of my methods are being executed etc...
```

Comment: You have no choice but to use reflection of some kind (dynamic assembly loading/type resolution/etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the assembly from wherever you like if you place an event handler on [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.7.2).  See [Resolving Assembly Loads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/resolve-assembly-loads)

Here's a blog post that has the essentials.  The key is timing.  You have to attach the event *before* the first method referencing the assembly is JITted.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/

Comment: Can you show me some example code? Dont forget that it is a library project

Comment: Thanks, my class was static and i changed it to normal. Now it works.